# How can I access password protected Excel workbook in Java using POI api

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I want to read from and write to password protected Excel files. How can I do so using Apache POI API.

Answer (score 21):

POI should be able to open both protected xls files (using *org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypt*) and protected xlsx files (using *org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt*). Have you tried these?

If you're using HSSF (for a xls file), you need to set the password before opening the file. You do this with a call to:

```
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);
```

After that, HSSF should be able to open your file.

For XSSF, you want something like:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("protect.xlsx"));
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
Decryptor d = new Decryptor(info);
d.verifyPassword(Decryptor.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
```

.

Alternately, in newer versions of Apache POI, [WorkbookFactory supports supplying the password when opening](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29), so you can just do something like:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("protected.xls"), "password");
```

That will work for both HSSF and XSSF, picking the right one based on the format, and passing in the given password in the appropriate way for the format.

Comment: When using NPOI is there any way to check if a file is password protected or not?

Comment: for XSSF it give this exception `org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files`

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ You need to install the proper JVM crypto, currently you're running with broken / nobbled low-strength crypto that can't handle anything modern

Answer (score 2):

If the entire workbook is password protected (by going through the Excel menu **File > Save As... > Tools > General Options...** then supplying a password) then the file is encrypted and you cannot read from and write to the workbook through POI.

[image: Excel Save As... General Options]

Answer (score 2):

CODE:

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("2.xls");         
BufferedInputStream bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);            
POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufferInput);            
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("test"); 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poiFileSystem, true);
```

jars used:

- commons-codec-1.5.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.jar
- jsr173_1.0_api.jar
- junit-4.11.jar
- log4j-1.2.13.jar
- poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- resolver.jar
- xbean.jar
- xbean_xpath.jar
- xmlbeans-qname.jar
- xmlpublic.jar

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation link provides in detail the encryption and decryption possibilities f for xls,xlsx and other supported formats: http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html

i.e. In case of `Binary Formats`(xls):

```
// XOR/RC4 decryption for xls
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass");
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("file.xls"), true);
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(null);
```

For XML based formats (xlsx):

```
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

try {
    if (!d.verifyPassword(password)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
    }

    InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(filesystem);

    // parse dataStream

} catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI is good api for excel processing.
But POI api provides only option to read the password protected excel files.
No option for writing the excel file with pasword.

[Create a password protected excel file using apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817290/create-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-apache-poi)

Check this thread for know more about password protected excel.

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided solutions worked for me for xlsx file, After various trial and errors I found this working.

Below is my working solution with poi-4.0.1.jar & poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar

```
private OutputStream getEncryptingOutputStream(POIFSFileSystem fileSystem, String password) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    EncryptionInfo encryptionInfo = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
    Encryptor encryptor = encryptionInfo.getEncryptor();
    encryptor.confirmPassword(password);
    return encryptor.getDataStream(fileSystem);
}

private void encryptSpreadSheet(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidFormatException
{
    try (POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem())
    {
      //sourcePath = "/var/tmp/dummy.xlsx"
      //destinationPath = "/var/tmp/dummy_encrypted.xlsx"
      try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(sourcePath));
            OutputStream out = getEncryptingOutputStream(fileSystem, "password");)
      {
         wb.write(out);
      }

      try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath)))
      {
          fileSystem.writeFilesystem(fileOutputStream);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myfile.xlsx"); 
    POIFSFileSystem pfs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);

    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(pfs);
    Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

    if (!d.verifyPassword("passwordForFile")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password!");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Correct password!");

        //InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(pfs);

        // parse dataStream
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to save excel file password protected using Apache POI.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Test.xlsx");

    XSSFSheet shtSummary = workbook.createSheet("Test");


    workbook.write(outputStream);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
        outputStream.close();
  }

  POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
  EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
  Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
  enc.confirmPassword("mypassword");

  OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("Test.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
  OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
  opc.save(os);
  opc.close();

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Test.xlsx");
  fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
  fos.close();
```

This code works great. This solution is for .xslx format.

The below code is for .xls format.

```
String fname = "Test.xls";

FileInputStream fileInput = null;
BufferedInputStream bufferInput = null;
POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = null;
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

try {
    fileInput = new FileInputStream(fname);
    bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
    poiFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufferInput);

    Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("mypassword");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poiFileSystem, true);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    cell.setCellValue("THIS WORKS!");

    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fname);
    workbook.writeProtectWorkbook(Biff8EncryptionKey.getCurrentUserPassword(), "");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
}
catch (Exception ex) {

    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
finally {
    try {

        bufferInput.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {

        fileOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Both the solution works for me. It's a great solution which I found working.