# create password protected excel file in java

Tags: excel, apache-poi, password-protection

I am in need to password protect excel file.That means when user tries to open excel he/she should be asked for password.

I am using apache poi but it seems like it does't have such option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: How can i password protect excel so that when user tries to open excel he/she should be asked for password

Comment: great, now what have you tried?

Comment: As i told I am using Apache POI there is some thing sheet.protectSheet("password") which makes sheet read only but there is nothing which solves my requirement.

Comment: In apache poi there is no such option.

Comment: what about [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817290/create-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-apache-poi) (*first result on google using "apache POI save excel with a password" in the search box*)?

Comment: No man.No help......Some comments says open source apis in java does't provide such feature.But it should not be the case.

Comment: "_Some comments says open source apis in java does't provide such feature.But it should not be the case._" Why do you think it should not be the case?