# Lock and password protect Excel (XLSX) file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to password protect an .xlsx excel file using Apache POI.

I am using an older version (3.8) of POI in my application. So is there any work around available for it. I want to protect all the worksheets as well the workbook. I am able to protect the worksheets but workbook is not getting password protected.

Comment: _I am using an older version of POI_ - you obviously understand that the version number matters. So why have you to posted the exact version you are using?

Comment: version number is 3.8 poi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a password protected excel file using apache poi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817290/create-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-apache-poi)

Comment: I've recently added a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51483) for various sheet protection settings, how about upgrading the poi version?