# styles.xml breaking password-protected XSSFWorkbook (Apache POI v3.16) save process

Tags: javascript, excel, apache-poi

Currently using Apache POI 3.16 on Java version 1.7.0-251 (Unix)

Taking a leaf out of the example explained by @Aniruddh Chandegra ([How to create and edit a password protect excel sheet using Apache POI 3.14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613972/how-to-create-and-edit-a-password-protect-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi-3-14))

[EDIT - Added the below code to show what I'm doing: creates XSSFWorkbook and extracts data, then encrypts]

Note: I'm running the code on - server-side Javascript - using Mozilla Rhino v1.7R3 which provides support for nearly all of ECMAScript Edition 5 plus a few features from Mozilla Javascript 1.8.

```
var wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
var createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

// Begin filling in rows/cells
addMostRecentSheet(wb);

var filepath = [hidden]
var fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filepath);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

var fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

var info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);
var enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword("password");

var os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
opc.saveImpl(os);  //<<-----Crash there - unable to save /x1/styles.xml
opc.close();

var fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filepath);
fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
fos.close();
```

I eventually managed to save password protected xlsx but I had to remove the styling of Date columns.

Below is the code to format cells into Date celltype:

```
function createDateCell(row, colNum, value)
{
    var cell;
    if (value)
    {
        cell = row.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        var cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle)
    }
    else
    {
        cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Yet when running the program, I keep getting this error, is there a workaround to keep the Date column type?
The error message:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: 
Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : 
The part /xl/styles.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@216fb8e
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the latest stable supported version?

Comment: @Gagravarr - fair question - that's the reason why I mentioned the Java version 1.7.0-251, the system I'm adopting Apache POI is fixed to that java version. The infrastructure doesn't allow me to upgrade the Java to match the latest version Apache POI is offering.

Comment: I'd try it on another box with the latest Java and Apache POI. Try that. That'll tell you if it is an Apache POI issue that's still present, or a known-fix you'll need to backport or workaround

Comment: @Gagravarr - I can't - like I said before, the system on the Unix box is fixed so I have to work with Apache POI 3.16 and Java 1.7.0-251. If I remove all styling (Date and setAutoColumnSize() and freezepane on first row - the encryption of the new excel works fine.

Comment: If it is a bug still in the latest version of Apache POI, you need to report it to the project, and help get it fixed (then backport). If it is already fixed on the latest version, use  http://poi.apache.org/changes.html to identify the fix(es) and backport. So, you still need to try on a more recent machine with a more recent version first...

Comment: Your `createDateCell` creates a new `CellStyle` for each cell. This is wrong. `CellStyle`s are on workbook level and are stored in `/xl/styles.xml`. If your `createDateCell` creates thousand date cells, then it also creates thousand times the same `CellStyle`. Thus the `/xl/styles.xml` contains thousand times the same `XML` for that `CellStyle`. Don't do that.

Comment: Instead do `var cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle(); cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));` only once on workbook level. Then hand over that one `CellStyle` to the cells creator function, like `function createDateCell(row, colNum, value, cellStyle)`.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Brillaint - it now works. The problem was I was repeating the creation of datestyle - as you clearly pointed out. I've now got it working - thank you.

Comment: I'm having an exception thrown just like this. I'm wondering.... in my case I create first a valid XLSX file without encryption.... then I translate it into an encrypted file. Why would it fail on the encryption if it was able to create a valid xlsx file on the first step? (By the way, I'm not using dates). I will see what I can do about data/styling to see if I can shrink the size of the style file to see if that helps, until I get some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: After some digging, was able to get rid of the problem by reusing styles instead of creating new ones.... this answer hinted what the problem was. Thanks. The question remains for me in terms of why it fails on encrypting if the original file was created fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create date style cells, you need to do this:

```
var wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
var createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
var dateStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
dateStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

You only need to do it once. By setting the cellStyle at the top, you've populated /xl/styles.xml only once.

When populating the cells, you simply add the dateStyle to the function:

```
createDateCell(row, colNum++, tables.SHE_SOUTH.DOB.value, dateStyle);
```

The function ***createDateCell*** simply add the cellStyle:

```
function createDateCell(row,colNum,value, cellStyle){
    var cell;
    if(value){
        cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
    else
    {
        cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

That way the /xl/styles.xml doesn't get bloated as before. Which allows the encryption of the workbook. Works a treat, with credit to [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter)

Comment: apart of repetitive content which might trigger the zip bomb detection, the encryption for OOXML based documents doesn't care about its content. IIRC you can stream / encrypt documents up to 2gb even POI can't read those later on because of OOM with the XML content