# Apache POI - How to password-protect excel with date cells?

Tags: javascript, excel, date, encryption, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to create password-protected excel, but it cannot work if I use the following:

```
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
cell.setCellValue(value);
var cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle)
```

The date values are number of days since 01/01/1900.

If I omit Date Formatting - the encryption works fine. 
Has anyone managed to have created a password-protected excel with date cells?

Comment: Not clear how you are using `apache poi` in `JavaScript`. But using `apache poi` in `Java` there is no issue using [XML-based formats - Encryption](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Encryption) if the workbook has cell style having date format.

Comment: @AxelRichter - I'm running the code on - server-side Javascript - using Mozilla Rhino v1.7R3 which provides support for nearly all of ECMAScript Edition 5 plus a few features from Mozilla Javascript 1.8 - And I'm getting errors only when using date formatting.

Comment: The source of the problem can be in ... 1) your script, 2) the mapping of rhino to java (i.e. datatypes/calls) or 3) POI.
Assuming you are using XSSF: As XSSF encryption wraps the whole (zip-) file in an OLE2 document, it doesn't care what data you fill in. what keeps me puzzled is, if you really meant encryption and not sheet protection - and if you maybe used HSSF.
Also how does the error look like? a) POI throws exception in writing the file, b) the file can't be opened, c) anything else?

Comment: @kiwiwings - It was a problem with my scripting as AxelRichter pointed out as I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter), the answer was solved at this question [styles.xml breaking password-protected XSSFWorkbook (Apache POI v3.16) save process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62242093/438094).

***Note:*** This code is for server-side Javascript - using Mozilla Rhino v1.7R3 which provides support for nearly all of ECMAScript Edition 5 plus a few features from Mozilla Javascript 1.8.

To create password-protected excel with date cells, the format of date cell are created once, not at each cell creation.

```
importPackage(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.util);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc);

//Create the workbook
var wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

//Add styling at the top
var createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
var dateStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
dateStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));

//Process the cells
//loop..
createDateCell(row, colNum++, tables.SHE_SOUTH.DOB.value, dateStyle);
//..end of loop

function createDateCell(row,colNum,value, cellStyle){
    var cell;
    if(value){
        cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
    else
    {
        cell = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }
    return cell;
}

//Write out the excel
var fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(path_and_filename);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

//Begin encryption
var fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
var info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192,
 HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);
var enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword("password");

var opc = OPCPackage.open(new java.io.File(path_and_filename), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
var os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
opc.save(os);
opc.close();

var fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(path_and_filename);
fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
fos.close();
```