# Is Apache POI support modify password protect xlsx file content?

Tags: apache-poi, password-protection

After I generate a password protected xlsx file with apache poi, I  modify file content with XSSFWorkbook.like:

```java
File file = new File("Test2.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(file, "password");
wb.createSheet("Test0001");
try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    wb.write(fileOutputStream);
} finally {
    wb.close();
}
```

when I reopen the file, the file was no longer password protected,Apache POI and poi-ooxml version:5.2.1.Maybe poi not support modify password protected xlsx file?

is there anyway modify password protected xlsx file with apache poi?

Comment: see comments under this (outdated) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8988121/724039

Comment: Thanks，I already see it,but not found any way to edit encrypt xlsx file with apache poi.

Comment: When you're done making changes, save with an encryption password rather than the clear-text save in your code? https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html