# Open a password protected Word/Excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-office, apache-poi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access password protected Excel workbook in Java using POI api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042694/how-can-i-access-password-protected-excel-workbook-in-java-using-poi-api)

How to open a password protected Word/Excel-file using Apache POI in Java ? 
Please, write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI support for reading encrypted XLSX and DOCX files. Refer the Apache POI [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Your code should be something like this:

```
 EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
    Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

    try {
        if (!d.verifyPassword(password)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
        }

        InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(filesystem);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
        // parse dataStream

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
    }
```

Comment: filesystem ? POIFSFileSystem filesystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("example.xls"));

Comment: Yes, filesystem mean POIFSFileSystem. http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.html