# How to set password for Excel(xls) file using java

Tags: java

I have created the excel file but i want protect my excel file and set the password. Please anyone help me how to set the password for my excel(.xls) file

Sample code:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
try {
    // Create a new workbook
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    // create styles to use in work book
    Map<String, HSSFCellStyle> styles = createStyles(workbook);

    HSSFSheet worksheet = null;

    if (individualVOList != null && !individualVOList.isEmpty()) {
        worksheet = workbook.createSheet(DBElement.INDIVIDUALS.getName());

        // Construct the header for the report
        constructPageHeader(worksheet, styles.get("pageTitle"), DBElement.INDIVIDUALS.getName());

        constructTableContent(worksheet, styles, individualVOList);
    }

    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    status = true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("[PL] - FileNotFoundException " + ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("[PL] - IOException " + ex);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to set a password in what you posted. Why do you expect a password to be set in the above code? Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354454/i-want-to-create-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-apache-poi-and-then-give/41357914

Answer (score 2):

From your code, you are using `HSSFWorkbook`, which has Javadoc [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html). In that Javadoc, there is a method called [writeProtectWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#writeProtectWorkbook-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). It looks like this:

```
public void writeProtectWorkbook(java.lang.String password,
                                 java.lang.String username)

protect a workbook with a password (not encypted, just sets writeprotect flags and the password.
```

(looks like they're missing a right parentheses in their javadoc, minor typo)

So in your code, the Javadoc says you could do something like this to protect the document with username `scooter`, password `s3cr3t`:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
workbook.writeProtectWorkbook("s3cr3t", "scooter");
```