# I am not able to fetch data from encrypted excel file. While fetching in java selenium, its throwing OLAP error

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I used poi jars from version 3 to 5 to fetch data from encrypted excel file but not able to fetch data, while running java selenium read excel program its throwing OLAP error. The excel file is .xlsx.

```
ERROR: xception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions
.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the
OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML 
(Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI
to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)
```

How to fetch the data from encrypted excel file?

Comment: Is there any `decryption` `password` for that workbook ? If yes, than you should provide that decryption password in your code to access the workbook.

Comment: see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042694/how-can-i-access-password-protected-excel-workbook-in-java-using-poi-api