# Apache POI. Insert an editing row between locked rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I have an excel file with table which cells are locked. I want to insert a new row between existing locked rows, but with editing abilities. Is it able in Apache POI?

I tried to use many different sheet protection options

Example of code:

```
var book = new SXSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = book.createSheet(SHEET_NAME);
sheet.protectSheet("password");
var unlockedStyle = book.createCellStyle();
unlockedStyle.setLocked(false);

var lockedStyle = book.createCellStyle();
lockedStyle.setLocked(true);

for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < 20; rowNum++) {
    var row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
    for (int colNum = 0; colNum < 10; colNum++) {
        var cell = row.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellStyle(lockedStyle);
    }
}

for (int colNum = 0; colNum < 10; colNum++) {
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(colNum, unlockedStyle);
}
```

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: updated post by adding code sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access password protected Excel workbook in Java using POI api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042694/how-can-i-access-password-protected-excel-workbook-in-java-using-poi-api)